# Modified Page Layout Not Updating the ASPX

Tags: sharepoint-online, page-layout

I've made changes to my .html , checked in and published the changes, but the .aspx is not updating.  The dates modified are:

HTML
1/13/2020 231p

ASPX
1/10/2020 240p

This is SharePoint Online.  Anyone know how to get them back in sync and get the ASPX to regenerate?

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to forget the HTML files and just edit the ASPX itself. HTML page layouts were a bad idea, fraught with problems like this, and in Online there is no recourse when things don't go as expected.

Comment: I get a Server error: This file may not be moved, deleted, renamed or otherwise edited when I try to save the aspx.  Is it because the page layout is still associated to a page?

Comment: I changed the page layout for my page, removed from available page layouts, was able to modify the HTML and then the ASPX converted properly.  Then reverted everything back.  I just wanted to make updates!